# Django CBV CreateView - Redirect from CreateView to last page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm learning Django and i have problem with redirecting back from CreateView I want to redirect to a BookDetail page which contains list of bookinstances which are created by CreateView.
models.py:

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library)."""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular book across whole library')
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('m', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=LOAN_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='m',
        help_text='Book availability',
    )


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['due_back']
        permissions = (("can_mark_returned", "Set book as returned"),)  

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.id} ({self.book.title})'

    @property
    def is_overdue(self):
        if self.due_back and date.today() > self.due_back:
            return True
        return False
```

views.py

```
class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = BookInstance
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
    initial = {'Book': Book}
    success_url = reverse_lazy('book-detail')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('book/create/instance', views.BookInstanceCreate.as_view(), name='book_create_instance'),
    path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
]
```

success_url seems to not work here since redirect url needs information about book primary key. I have already tried few options ex. `

```
next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
return HttpResponseRedirect(next)

return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

but it seems to not work for me. Can someone instruct me how to edit View so it will redirect after submiting a form?

Edit: there is my template code:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class='btn btn-dark'>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the `get_success_url` method, rather than the static `success_url` attribute:

```
class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    ...
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: How do i access primary key for this detail view? I used: 
    class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = BookInstance
        fields = '__all__'
        permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
        initial = {'Book': Book}
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.book.pk})

and now i have error:
AttributeError at /catalog/book/create/instance

'BookInstanceCreate' object has no attribute 'book'

Comment: It should be `self.object.pk`.

Comment: Still got the error :Reverse for 'book-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': UUID('25f6ba52-2b6e-45cd-859d-dcc4e79f30ec')}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/book/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$'] </br> I think the problem is because I am adding a BookInstance and want to redirect back to a Book detail page not Bookinstance. "PK" that i want to access is in Book(model) > get_absolute_url

Comment: Hang on, is Book the same as BookInstance? And I'm confused about the UUID there, the reason you get the error is that your URL is expecting a numeric id not a UUID.

Comment: I solved it i had to use : `self.object.book.pk` as book was a foreignkey for bookinstance, self.object.pk was getting the `id` from BookInstance model. Thanks for help I wasted several hours on this before i i posted.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! ```python self.object.book.pk ```