# how can i redirect the user to the newly created post after creating a new post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want the user to be redirected to the newly created post i tried adding

`return reverse("article-detail", args=(str(self.pk)))` but it doest work.
in command prompt it says `

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'article-detail'
> with arguments '('4', '3')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['article/(?P[0-9]+)$']

`

> models.py

```
Class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='coding')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article-detail", args=(str(self.pk)))
        # return reverse("home")
```

> urls.py

```
path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name="add_post"),
path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article-detail"),
```

> views.py

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823773/5644965

Comment: i tried it but it shows                      No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

Comment: `args` should be a list of items,. Can you add your url pattern where you have `reverse("article-detail"`?

Comment: i have added the url

Comment: But no! I meant the url linked to that name `article-detail`. And add the full traceback.. this is how I can help you

Comment: i added the url also the traceback i got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_absolute_url` method is not correct, with reverse you either use `kwargs` to provide arguments as **dict** or `args` as **list**. In your case, you should do it with list as I mentioned in comments above.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("article-detail", args=[self.pk])
```

Comment: Dude no Homo but i love you man i almost  gave up on this thanks alot man

Comment: can u please tell me why wasnt my code working because i was following a guy from youtube who wrote it it like this and it worked for him

Comment: He may have been used a tuple to provide the arguments. -> Add a comma at the end:  `(self.pk, )`

Answer (score 0):

in your addpostview class you can  specify your success url.

```
 `class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model=Post
    form_class=PostForm
    template_name='add_post.html'
    success_url='article/article_id/'`
```

Comment: can you post the  post detail view class ?

Answer (score 0):

why not rewrite the get absolute url like this. i guess because you specify th url path id as int and you are converting it to str in get absolute url

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("article-detail", kwargs={pk:self.pk})
```